# Use word iterator in a string

Tags: c++, iterator

istream_iterator is very useful to get words from a istream like this:

```
istrem_iterator<string> my(my_istream);
while (my != end) {
   std::cout << *my << std::endl;
   ++my;
}
```

I would like to do the same with a string.

Is there a way to do this ? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) provides a input stream interface for `std::string`s:

```
std::istringstream my_istream(my_string);
```

You can then use an `std::istream_iterator<std::string>` with this, as you did before, to extract words.

---

You can write your code with `std::copy` like so:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(my_istream),
          std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
          std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Comment: Thanks! but I have got an issue. I'm trying my_istream.str(str) to fill it the first time. But the second time I try it with an other str it does not work. I searched on the man: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/ and do not found the method to reset it. Have you got any ideas ?

Comment: @nsvir In what way doesn't it work? Using `str` should change the underlying string.

Comment: @nsvir Also note that that website is not "the man". It's an unofficial C++ reference.

Comment: I have got a while(getline(istream, str)) and I file my_istream with the new str. I think I'm missing something like clearing my_istream

Comment: @nsvir So you're extracting lines from `my_istream` into `str`. You then want to iterate over the words in `str`? In that case, you need a new stream `std::istringstream my_ss(str)` which you can then iterate over.

Comment: Ok I get it! Thanks! :)